# KeyPress won't work

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener, keyevent

For some reason my program doesn't detect when I press a key even though it should be fine.

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    Second s = new Second();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.add(s);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setTitle("Bouncing Ball");
    f.setSize(600, 400);
}

}
```

This is the Second class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

 import javax.swing.*;

public class Second extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
double x = 0, y = 0, velX =0 , velY = 0;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Rectangle2D circle = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40);
    g2.fill(circle);
    t.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    repaint();
}

public void up() {
    velY = -1.5;
    velX = 0;
}

public void down() {
    velY = 1.5;
    velX = 0;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int KeyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if (KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_Z) {
        up();
    }

    if (KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        down();
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

}

}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try debugging and setting breakpoints inside your `keyPressed` function?

Comment: For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

- The reason the timer doesn't appear to work is because, `velX` and `velY` are equals to 0, so, it doesn't increment anything. If you give them a value, it will animate.
- The reason the Keys won't work is

  1. because you haven't registered the `KeyListener` to the panel.
  2. you need to `setfocusable(true)`.
  3. You need to call `repaint()` in the either the `up()` `down()` methods *or* in the `keyPressed()` method.
  4. You need to increment/decrement the `y` value in the `up()` and `down()` methods.

---

Add the below constructor, add the `repaint()` to the `keyPressed()` and increment/decrement correctly and it works

```
public Second(){
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
}
```

Add the above constructor. And the repaint in the keyPressed

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int KeyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if (KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_Z) {
        up();
        repaint();
    }

    if (KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        down();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Increment/Decrement

```
public void up() {
    y -= 10;
}

public void down() {
    y += 10;
}
```

---

Though this may work, it is recommended to use key bindings.

**See** [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) | [The complete Creating a GUI with Swing trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, add a listener to the JFrame and see if you get any response there. If you do, then it means that the JFrame isn't passing the events down to the Second, probably because the Second doesn't have focus.

You could also try calling `requestFocusInWindow()`:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html

> A component generally gains the focus when the user clicks it, or when the user tabs between components, or otherwise interacts with a component. A component can also be given the focus programmatically, such as when its containing frame or dialog-box is made visible. This code snippet shows how to give a particular component the focus every time the window gains the focus:

```
//Make textField get the focus whenever frame is activated.
> f.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
>     public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
>         s.requestFocusInWindow();
>     } });
```

I would also recommend using more descriptive variables than `s`, `f`, and a more descriptive class name than `Second`.